# I am getting error while Starting Tsung

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to use uTsung but I am getting below error

```
Starting Tsung
{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',error_handler,get_files}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

How do it resolve this?

Comment: I have even tried using different versions of erlang. But I am not getting proper version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually because you've updated your Erlang version and try to compile Tsung on a different version of Erlang.

If you're using the packaged version of Tsung then you need to uninstall it and reinstall it so it gets the right version of Erlang. Alternatively, if you're using Tsung from source then recompile it.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan. I tried it and I could resolve it by compiling tsung code.

Comment: I am getting new issue now. i.e. Kernel PID terminated.